# I'm trying to go to another page when clicking a button. How could i do this (WinUI 3)

Tags: xaml, uwp, winui, windows-template-studio

I'm trying to go to another page when clicking a button. How could i do this.

I tried using a [`NavigationViewItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.navigationviewitem?view=winrt-22621) but it didn't work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The `NavigationViewItem` you posted is used in **UWP**.

If it is a WinUI3 project, then you need to refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.page?view=windows-app-sdk-1.1#examples), use `Navigate`.

the relevant code samples are as follows.

**xaml**

```
<Button x:Name="myButton" Click="myButton_Click"/>
```

---

**xaml.cs**

```
private void myButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    Frame rootFrame = new Frame();          
    this.Content = rootFrame;

    rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage1), null);
      
}
```